# Finding Smith Normal Form of the Inverse of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, smith-normal-form

Suppose I have a $N\times N$ integer matrix $A$ that has the Smith normal form $diag[a_1, a_2,...a_N]$, and we have a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I_N$. Is there an easy way to find the Smith normal form of $B$? Or can we say anything about the invariant factors of $B$?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: adding essential information that $A$ is an integer matrix

Comment: What are the entries of $A$? integers? in a ring? in a field?

Comment: They are integers. I'm sorry that I forgot to add this essential information

Comment: Assuming $\ B\ $ must also have integer entries, then $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ must both be unimodular, and $\ I_N\ $ must be the Smith normal form of both of them.